# Changing Google Maps markers by ID

Tags: google-maps

I'm developing a website like Airbnb and I'd like to change marker icon when user mouseover the listing box.

Here is the structure of my listing page:
On the left side of the screen, there are listing div's with unique id's.
On the right side, there is a Google Map and the markers with the same id of listing div.
What I'm trying to do is when a user mouseover on listing div, change the marker's icon that has the same id.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way (and the only way that I know how) is to keep track of the markers when they are created with the divs on the left, an on a hover event, you then call say divarray[i].marker.setIcon(newimage) to change the image.

Comment: I'm creating markers in getJSON function like this:
`var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: latLng,
              map: map,
              icon: image,
              title: data.id,
              id: data.id,
              optimized: false
          });`
How can I create the divs on left?

Comment: If you're using jquery, you'd just add the html using .append("<div></div"); to the listing div, but that would depend on what you are using.  How are you manipulating the dom?